# Wordpress Codex has different number of arguments for get_previous_post and get_next_post functions. Why?

Tags: codex

Compare the following two links:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post

The get_previous_post function **doesn't** have the last $taxonomy parameter, while get_next_post has it listed. I followed those instruction literally, which caused my get_previous_post to break. When I noticed the difference between the two functions, I tried specifying the taxonomy in my get_previous_post function, which fixed the problem. Is this a mistake in the Codex for get_previous_post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Codex does not document the `$taxonomy` argument. Without digging into it, my assumption would be that maybe it originally was not one of the arguments and no one ever bothered to change the Codex.

The Codex, while still a tremendous resource of information, is (1) user generated/curated content and can be prone to mistakes, and (2) is no longer the "official" documentation of WP core functions, hooks, and APIs.  That status belongs to https://developer.wordpress.org/.

On the developer site, the `$taxonomy` argument IS documented for `get_previous_post()`.  Since that data literally comes from the WP core inline documentation, that right there tells you that the Developer Docs are correct and the Codex is wrong.

See:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/

Comment: That historical context makes a ton of sense to me. Thanks for clearing that up! My big takeaway, then, is: use the developer documentation, not the codex.

Comment: I'd say *start* with the developer documentation. For additional information, the Codex certainly *can* yield good ideas and examples, but it can also be stale and/or out-of-date (depending on the page). When it doubt though, the developer docs will be correct. And the Codex is a wiki. If you find a mistake, you can (and maybe should) correct it if you feel so inclined.